# Erro 503 - Localhost

Tags: php, apache

Acabei de formatar meu notebook. Instalei o *Ubuntu 18.04*, *Apache*, *MySQL* e *PHP*. Porém ao entrar na página `localhost`, recebo o seguinte erro:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gjfc.png]

Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: Qual conteúdo do arquivo `index.php`? Quais erros registrados nos logs do PHP e Apache?

Answer (score -1):

Parece-me que não tens o *Apache* iniciado. Tenta isto:

```
# Para ver se o tens o Apache iniciado:
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 status

# Para iniciar o Apache:
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Talvez tenhas que fazer o mesmo com o *MySQL*.

Comment: Ainda está a mesma coisa, o apache está inciado mas continua dando o mesmo erro